# MVC : how to select specific column/field from model object for drop down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following model & simple drop down in the view. I want to populate the customer name in the drop down. I tried following code but it did not work, can anybody please tell how to specify the column with dropdownselect statement.

**Model**

```
public class customer
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

}
```

//////////////////////////

```
  @{
Layout = null;
}

@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    @Html.DropDownList("name",Model);

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownList("name",new SelectList(Model,"id","name"));
```

**Update:**

Your model does not have name property. It only contains objects that have name property. You should update your model to reflect this:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<customer> CustomerList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

Then strongly type your view to this type:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

Then you can create the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomer , new SelectList(Model.CustomerList ,"id","name"));
```

Comment: How to do it with DropDownListFor? I tried following but did not work :(   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name, new SelectList(Model,"id","name"));